Viability of asking general or simple questions?
I am new to this site and have been largely stumped by a lot of scientific concepts presented like, “ What would happen if earth had a 50% tilt? “ (simplified version of a question I saw earlier and was more sophisticated when asked by the OP) or any question on a specific change size of a planet, air pressure, gravitational pull from a moon or other mass. from my understanding I can’t go around asking, “ What is _______ (insert scientific concept) and how does it work? “
What is the limit on questions to broaden your understanding of scientific research?
What are some resources to broaden my knowledge so I can adequately understand, ask, and answer questions on this site?
For further context I’m younger and have either not learned these things or have dutifully avoided remembering them in my course through the school system; just recently started my first try at world building, actually making a coherent story, at least semi-realistic new biological creatures and sentient fantasy species, and kinda fumbling around in the dark. Also I know this is a very broad ask since I need to learn a-lot of different things so just a list of good topics to research would be nice.
idk what else tags to add for this but discussion.

"What is the limit on questions to broaden your understanding of scientific research?" If you're suggesting that you need to understand scientific concepts, in order to do any worldbuilding - that's not really the case. Worldbuilding.SE isn't "physics-lite" and the process of building a world is far from "grab all science textbooks you can find and grind them into a world". You should probably clarify your goal in asking questions - whether you need some science, whether you need to reach some goal, and whether that goal even requires scientific knowledge.

or have dutifully avoided remembering them in my course through the school system - I laughed at that quote. First because it was funny and secondly because ye gods do I feel called out by it. There is a certain type of learning that can only be fed by curiosity, not by fiat. I used to hate history in school, now I find learning about events that interest me can be very soothing.

It's worth understanding Stack Exchange
Stack Exchange is not meant to replace an education. That's a brutal statement, but it's the truth. From the Help Center we read:

Search, and research
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Stack Exchange is not designed to be the first place people go for answers. It's literally designed to be the last place people go. The goal of the service is to help people solve specific problems that can't be solved via other means by tapping into the expertise of others.
We, the user community, understand there is a line between an education and practical reality. As an example, information about basic astronomy and celestial mechanics can be found almost anywhere on the Internet. But information about the gravitational consequences of a binary planet orbiting a trinary star system aren't. We do our best to address difficulties like this while reminding people that Stack Exchange isn't a free research service and that they are expected to try to cross that unfortunately vague and subjective line before asking here.
It's also worth understanding what an ideal question on Worldbuilding looks like
I mentioned the phrases "specific problem" and "not a free research service." Those perspectives are built into the user experience of Stack Exchange. From the rules you find in the Help Center to the question closure reasons, it's all based on the idea that you aren't looking to learn something new, but are trying to solve a problem you've run into. That means there's a good way to ask questions and a bad way, and which way an individual uses has a lot to do with whether they're trying to learn something (e.g., brainstorm ideas) or solve a specific problem.
Bad: I have an Earth-like planet that's identical to Earth in every way except it's tilted 50°, how would this affect the planet's climate?
On the surface this looks like a reasonable question. In reality the question shows no research and has no limits, no goals, no restrictions, and no expectations. An entire library of books could be written addressing the issue (not a specific problem...). In other words, the OP is trying to understand climatology (a particularly complex subject). We see questions like this a LOT and work with them as best we can (and yes, they're often closed...), but it's not the kind of question that's appropriate on Stack Exchange.
Good: I have an Earth-like planet that's identical to Earth in every way except it's tilted 50°. I've studied the seven pressure belts of Earth, but I cannot find information that explains the impact of the additional tilt on the equatorial low belt. Would the additional tilt result in a wider equatorial low pressure belt?
I hope it's obvious that the good example — intentionally simplistic for the purpose of this post — is very specific, demonstrates research, and identifies a problem the querent is trying to solve vs. the request for an education the bad example demonstrates.
It could be said that the difference is that a good question demonstrates the querent already has knowledge about their problem and needs help through clarification, not education.
One of the most valuable skills you can learn is how to ask questions
Whether it's dealing with search engines, navigating your nation's tax code, working through a ridiculous automated phone service, or asking someone you like out on a date, learning how to ask questions is astoundingly valuable. In a sense, it's the ability to know what you don't know or, better said, it's the ability to help people understand what specific information you're looking for so they don't feel like their time's been wasted or that you don't feel like you're in some kind of living hell because you can't figure out where next to go on the automated phone menu.
Therefore, I second and cheer @L.Dutch's admonition to use our Sandbox. It's purpose is to help you understand how to ask questions both on Stack Exchange and here on Worldbuilding.
However, if your goal is to learn new things...
Yeah. You're in the wrong place if that's your goal. It's often a happy byproduct of getting a problem solved, but if you need that education before you can explain your problem, that's not a step Stack Exchange is prepared to take. About that we sincerely apologize, but that's how our Stack Exchange Overlords designed their service.

Thanks for asking this question before starting asking actual questions and get bashed by the community.
First of all, questions aiming to broaden your understanding of scientific research are not meant for worldbuilding. Without reaching the depths of Youtube tutorials explaining how to drink a glass of water, the internet is full of explanations on how things work. Wikipedia is usually a decent starting point.
After that Stack Exchange communities have good insights too. It's usually difficult that questions related to real world topic have never been asked before: survivalism, planetary physics, science, etc. either here on Worldbuilding or on any sister community (Physics, the great outdoor, Space exploration, etc.) are just waiting for your search query to show you all their treasures. By reading questions and answers there, you might get insights and further references for your search.
Then, when you think you have a good question for us, you can post it in the sandbox and get help from our members to improve it if needed.

Food For Thought

As I read your question I see something akin to a question of worldbuilding process. How do I even do this? While I think it's admirable to delve into the sciences and learn about all the things you either haven't learnt yet or have already forgotten, I find that there is much to be said for the Naive School of worldbuilding.

What I mean by this is that you don't have to digest all those scientific facts in order to make a wonderful fictional world! In fact, one of the great struggles that has gone on under the surface here in WB.SE is the out of balance nature that scientific thinking brings to worldbuilding. The notion that either the fictional world must comply with real world science or that real world science must always inform the creation of fictional worlds. The strange idea that one can not have a good fictional world unless it mirrors or mimics the real.

It's not my goal to dissuade you from learning math and science or from using math and science to further art. But I would caution against too much reliance on science. You're allowed to grope in the dark. You're allowed (and I would say encouraged) to go forth and make worlds even if you don't know what you're doing yet!

In addition to the excellent answers you've already gotten, I would only add the following:
Our very own list of Worldbuilding Resources

For this I’ve unfortunately made one of my power systems “rules” which just means understanding of how things are built and work to manipulate them, so ive been working on semi realistic biology on the principle and partly to sneak in a shapeshifting character. Not complaining about the process (all that much) but definitely a little gruffed about learning how to draw what I want. All in all, done in by my own hands.
